# Divide two queries in SQL then group by

Tags: sql, group-by

I am looking for the rate change between new accounts and all accounts, I have both queries listed below. I need to divide NewAccounts by AllAccounts, take that percentage and group by town in the same query. Thanks

```
SELECT DISTINCT  Count(NewAccounts), Town
FROM   (SELECT Stuff)
WHERE   (Newaccounts)
Group By Town
;
SELECT DISTINCT  Count(AllAccounts), Town
FROM   (SELECT DifferentSTUFF)
WHERE   (AllAccounts)
Group By Town
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to rewrite your queries as subqueries and join them together:

```
SELECT  CAST(na.NewAccounts AS FLOAT) / aa.AllAccounts
FROM    (   SELECT Count(NewAccounts) AS NewAccounts, Town
            FROM   (SELECT Stuff)
            WHERE   (Newaccounts)
            GROUP BY Town
        ) na
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT Count(AllAccounts) AS AllAccounts, Town
            FROM   (SELECT DifferentSTUFF)
            WHERE   (AllAccounts)
            GROUP BY Town
        ) aa
            ON aa.Town = na.Town;
```

*n.b. I have removed `DISTINCT` from both queries as it is redundant. The cast to float on `NewAccounts` is to avoid the implicit conversion of the result integer division back to an integer.*

You may need to alter this slightly depending on the availability of data in each of the queries, i.e. if you won't always have a result in the new accounts for a town it would be better written as:

```
SELECT  CAST(COALESCE(na.NewAccounts, 0) AS FLOAT) / aa.AllAccounts
FROM    
        (   SELECT Count(AllAccounts) AS AllAccounts, Town
            FROM   (SELECT DifferentSTUFF)
            WHERE   (AllAccounts)
            GROUP BY Town
        ) aa
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT Count(NewAccounts) AS NewAccounts, Town
            FROM   (SELECT Stuff)
            WHERE   (Newaccounts)
            GROUP BY Town
        ) na
            ON aa.Town = na.Town
```

Comment: This worked perfect. Thank you. I was subquering them without the inner join.

Comment: How can I reduce the decimal down to two places? (I tried to replace Float with decimal and cast with convert)

Comment: Just cast the full result as well as either the denominator or the numerator: `CAST(CAST(COALESCE(na.NewAccounts, 0) AS FLOAT) / aa.AllAccounts AS DECIMAL(10, 2))`